# Ocaml how to summing individual elements with tail recursion?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

The thing is simple i think, the problem is:
With a given int list as example [25;30;45;60] return a int list with values [25;30+25;45+30+25;60+45+30+25].

I have 2 versions of the code (no one works).

```
let accu_weather lst =
    let rec aux acc lst2 = function 
        | [] -> []
        | h::t -> aux((acc+h) lst2::(h+acc)) lst
    in 0 []

let accu_weather lst =

    let rec accu lst2 = function
        | [] -> []
        | [x] -> x
        | h::t -> (h+accu(t))::lst2

    in accu List.rev(lst)
```

Someone knows the solution, and what im doing wrong?? 
Thanks!!

Comment: Pick one of the two attempts and tell us a little bit more about your problem. What exactly happens when you run the code?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote,

```
let accu_weather lst =
    let rec aux acc lst2 = function 
        | [] -> []
        | h::t -> aux((acc+h) lst2::(h+acc)) lst
    in 0 []
```

First, here

```
in 0 []
```

You're applying `0` to an empty list. That doesn't make sense. There you should be making some call to your auxiliary function with the right arguments.

And here,

```
| h::t -> aux((acc+h) lst2::(h+acc)) lst
```

You are applying `aux` to `((acc+h) lst2::(h+acc))` and `lst`. What is the type of your first argument? and what is `lst`?

I'd suggest you start with a simpler exercise first. Such as just calculating the sum of the elements of the list (using an accumulator).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let rec accu list = 
    match list with 
    |[] -> [] 
    |l::[] -> [l] 
    |l::l1::r -> l::accu ((l1+l)::r);;
```

Comment: This is not tail-recursive.